# HidlStatus: Attempted to retrieve value from failed HIDL call: Status(-1972947428)

Tags: android, interface, hidl

1、I add a new hidl interface in android.
2、The code has compiled successful.
3、but when test goes to call the interface,return this error.
I never meet this error and don't have a good idea to fix it,I derive to fix the error!